# Why are solids and liquids ignored in the equilibrium constant?

Tags: equilibrium

If a reaction is taking place and is going towards equilibrium, wouldn’t the reactant be consumed to form products and vice versa? If this reactant/product is a solid or liquid, wouldn’t the number of moles when the reaction reaches equilibrium decrease/increase from its initial number of moles? Wouldn’t this change in moles from start of reaction to point of equilibrium be important to the equation, since it’s a ratio of products to reactants at equilibrium?

Comment: Well there isn't quite enough information to answer the question. A specific problem would allow a precise answer. However, in general, products in another phase don't appear in the equilibrium expression. So in a solution, gaseous or solid products wouldn't be used in the equilibrium expression.

Answer (score 1):

A solid or liquid that should take part in a solution or gas phase reaction has to dissolve or evaporate before it can react in any meaningful way.

If you add more solid solute to a saturated solution, its concentration does not change, and so doesn't the equillibrium constant of a reaction of the dissolved solute.

(The solute might also react directly out of the solid. Theoretically. But this *different* reaction needs much more energy than the one from solution, and it will only add a minuscule shift to the total equillibrium, even if your solid has a huge surface. Surely neglectable, most likely not even measurable.)